# How to filter redux store data on several places

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

If I have redux store with list of cars.

And I use that list to populate several components like dropdown and for example table (which can be filtered).

When I filter table, my dropdown will be filtered to, 
beside it's on other page, they share same store.

And if I clone that part of data in store I would loose option to add/edit on all places.

What are best practices for this kind of cases? And examples maybe?

Comment: The redux documentation has a filtering example http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html#containersvisibletodolistjs

Comment: For best practices I highly recommend a read on this to start with keeping in mind the **Law of Demeter** when thinking about **actions**: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid editing the store data from inside the components.
When you filter your list in the component - create a new, cloned instance of the list - to be sure you don't change anything in the store.

When you want to change anything in the store - use actions.

You should keep the Store data as readonly in Components.

I found a good article on this topic https://hackernoon.com/redux-step-by-step-a-simple-and-robust-workflow-for-real-life-apps-1fdf7df46092

Comment: Absolutely agreed, in the professional environments I have worked you do store data manipulation in actions and pass that along to components to be rendered for the user

Comment: I didn't say I would change anything on store inside component..
If by any means I would change anything I would use actions.

I am talking about filtering data on multiple places and about some practices about that problem.
Also If I create new instance of list I would lose "single source of truth" as I said above, and that's one of point's of redux, to have data on one place - one store.

Comment: From your question I understand that you filter the list and assign the result (after filtering) to the same instance, which comes from the store. If you could provide a code example how you do the filtering it will be a lot easier to answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see this article explains this question well, didn't see it earlier:

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html

So this could be correct way to filter or do anything else without polluting the store data.